# How to get the status of printer and the job sent to a printer using wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

How to get the status of printer and the job sent to a printer using wxWidgets.
Find the printer.

Things I have to do is:
1. Find a printer.
2. Check the status of the printer.
3. Send the job to print.
4. Return ack after the job fails/Completes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you studied the wxWidgets printing overview?

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_printingoverview.html

Comment: but it doesn't send any response after the job is done or if the job fails inst it??

Comment: What doesn't send any response?  What does 'inst it' mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the last error right after the call to `print`, like this:

```
wxPrinter printer;
MyPrintout printout("My printout");
printer.Print(this, &printout, true);
wxPrinterError errorCode = printer.GetLastError();
```

The return values can be:

```
wxPRINTER_NO_ERROR    No error happened.
wxPRINTER_CANCELLED   The user cancelled printing.
wxPRINTER_ERROR       There was an error during printing.
```

For further reference check here: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxprinter.html#wxprinterprint